# FacebookClient class is not visible in my class file

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I am using visual studio 2008.I am creating a facebook application.For that I have taken file of facebook C# sdk from codeplex of version 5.And added a code for upload photo but The  FacebookClient class is not visible in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that it's not showing up because you are using VS2008.  The SDK expects VS2010.

Comment: ya now I am using VS 2010.Still having a problem.I added all dll from \Bin\Release\Net40 from this.using Facebook;using Facebook.Web;
using Facebook.Web.Mvc;using Newtonsoft.Json;but unabled to get contract dll.